# Disable fancybox within viewports in Media Queries

Tags: mobile, css, fancybox, media-queries, responsive-design

I'm wondering if there's a quick solution to killing my fancybox calls at resolutions below 480px for mobile within my media queries. So that items that used the fancybox, just won't use it below certain resolutions and will be linked directly to the .html page (I'm using iFrame fancyboxs).

I've just tried display: none; on the fancybox class I'm using at the certain viewports and no success.

```
.fancybox-iframe { display: none; }
```

Comment: why you don't evaluate the `viewport` first? and if `viewport > 480` then load fancybox + custom scripts (it's easier to load something IF a condition is `true` than remove/kill it). There are several questions/answers about how to detect the `viewport` and how to create scripts (`document.createElement('script');`) if a condition exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media queries are finicky things. Some CSS properties can be use, while some can't. Display is one of those properties, I believe.

I find it best to set a `max-width` to 0px.